# Correct Password Storage for Git Repositories

Tags: java, git, repository, password-protection, jgit

I'm building an application in which you can manage GIT repositories.

I have chosen to store the repository information in a database, but I'm having a problem with the passwords.

Problem:
When i encounter a https + password secured repository i will need to store the password.
If i want to push changes on the repository, i will need the password as plain text.

If i hash the password, i'm not able to reuse it.
What would be a good secure solution to store these passwords, without storing them as plain text?

I'm using Java with the JGit library.

Thanks.

Comment: Store them in an SQLite Database (plain text) and encode it with [SQLcipher](http://sqlcipher.net/). The problem of storing the passwords is not as much of a problem, as the fact that the password will be in your memory at least when you use it.

Answer (score 1):

You're going to have to store them as plain text at some level: as you said, your application depends on having the password.

How you store them depends on what level of user interaction you're able to deal with, and which systems you're running on -- on Gnome desktops, you could integrate with `seahorse`, on Windows, you might be able to use the credentials vault.  If you're not able to integrate, copying the approach taken by something like KeePass might be a good idea.

If you can't interact with the user at all, you're probably just as well storing the data unencrypted, as you'll have to store the encryption key anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Try BouncyCastle [1]. It comes with a large number of encryption algorithms under a liberal license.

[1] http://www.bouncycastle.org/java.html

Comment: That avoids having it in clear text, but you then have the "encryption key" which again is sort of a password that you need to store somewhere, at least in code, where it can be decompiled easily with byte-code based programming languages like Java, best option would be to use OS-support, but with Java you likely need to implement that on your own.